# unable to deploy nuxt application?

Tags: iis, web-deployment, nuxt.js

Im trying to deploy nuxt on my iis server. I have node downloaded and running npm build in the terminal works perfect but it is located on local host. How do I get it to deploy to port 80.

Running generate works on port 80 but it is a static site which doesnt work for my application.

I would like to avoid downloading anything additional to my server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could try to use IIS ARR(Application Request Routing) to achieve your requirement. You could download it from this [url](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/application-request-routing).

Notice: There is no way to achieve your requirement without downloading anything.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Install the ARR for your IIS.

[image]

2.Make sure your nuxt application could run well on your local machine by using npm or something else. For exmaple: localhost:3000

[image]

3.Create a new application on your IIS default application.

[image]

4.Then you could open the ARR and enable the reverse proxy

[image]

[image]

[image]

5.Open the defailt web sites's app which you have created in IIS and click the url rewrite button

6.Select reverse proxy

[image]

7. Type in the url you have run on the npm or other tool. E.g localhost:3000

8.Then you could access it by using http://localhost/app url.

Notice:

You should modify the vue-ruter to use the new route url.

[image]

Then you could modify the url rewirte rule which have created before to add the app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
server: {
    port: 80, // default: 3000
    host: 'localhost' // default: localhost
  }
```

In nuxt.config